# Make links clickable in Google Sheets errors

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a Google Sheets add-on.

When the sheet doesn't contain some data that the add-on expects, I'm able to display an error message by throwing an error in my Google Apps Script.

```
...
if (!sheet) {
  throw new Error('(GA Bot For TWs) No "Metadata" sheet found. ' +
    'https://gabot.glitch.me/errors/metadata.html');                           
}
...
```

Gets rendered as:

[image: screenshot of example error in google sheets]

Is there a way to make `https://gabot.glitch.me/errors/metadata.html` clickable?

I'm aware that I can display custom modals, but I'm specifically interested in adding a custom link to the error message.

Comment: Try>catch>Browser.msgBox('link') ?

Comment: `Browser.msgBox` will only display plaintext. And no, you cannot customize the red error bar. You could use `HtmlService` to create a custom, interactive dialog and the `getUi()` method to display a popup or sidebar.